# Samping without replacement and expected value

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Suppose you have a deck that contains $n$ cards, with $r$ red cards and $n-r$ black cards. You draw $k$ cards from the deck. What is the expected value of the number of red cards you draw?

This is an exam question I was given recently that I completely flunked. I've mostly been taught sampling with replacement/iid random variable techniques so I faltered pretty significantly here. How would I solve a problem like this? I'm assuming you have to do some combinatorics stuff but I don't know how to construct it.

Comment: If $X$ is the number of red cards you draw then $X$ has a hypergeometric distribution (assuming you're sampling w/o replacement) whose expected value is naturally $$\mathbb{E}(X)=k\cdot \frac{r}{n}$$

Comment: Okay sure, but we were not taught the hypergeometric distribution, meaning we were meant to derive the answer here without the use of the known expected value of this family of distributions. Any idea on how to derive this result from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_j=1$ if the $j^{\text{th}}$ sampled card is red and $X_j=0$ otherwise.  Then $P(X_j=1)=\frac{r}{n}$ for all $1\leq j\leq k$. Although $X_1,...,X_k$ aren't independent, we can use linearity of expectation to say the expected value of $S=X_1+\dots +X_k$ is $$\mathbb{E}(S)=\sum_{j=1}^k\mathbb{E}(X_j)=k\cdot \frac{r}{n}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response--but I don't understand why $P(X_j=1)$ is always going to be equal to $\tfrac{r}{n}$. Surely if $X_1=1$, then $P(X_2=1)=\tfrac{r-1}{n-1}$ since we are sampling without replacement?

Comment: Great question. Actually, we have $P(X_2=1|X_1=1)={r-1 \over n-1}$ while $P(X_2=1)={r \over n}.$ To see why, use total law of probability: $$\begin{eqnarray*}P(X_2=1)&=&P(X_2=1|X_1=0)P(X_1=0)+P(X_2=1|X_1=1)P(X_1=1) \\ &=& \frac{r}{n-1}\cdot \frac{n-r}{n}+\frac{r-1}{n-1}\cdot \frac{r}{n} \\ &=& \frac{r}{n}\end{eqnarray*}$$